# Is it bad practice to declare a C function as static if it can still be executed indirectly (through a callback function)?

Tags: c++, c, linker, embedded, compiler-optimization

I have a C module for an embedded system (`foo.c`, `foo.h`) that contains a function `my_driver_fn()` that is local in scope from an API perspective (e.g. not in `foo`'s public header: any other code that uses its API via `#include "foo.h"`  should not be allowed to call this function). Assume `my_driver_fn()` is reentrant.

However, `foo` uses a library `libdostuff` that needs to be initialized with a few user-supplied callback functions (architecture/hardware specific things) for it to work properly on any platform. In `foo`, `my_driver_fn` mentioned above would be one of the functions in question...needed by `libdostuff`, but not by anyone that uses `foo`.

**Is it bad form, dangerous, disadvantageous, handicapping the compiler in any way, or undefined behavior that the compiler could capitalize on, for these callback functions (`my_driver_fn()` to be declared as `static` within `foo.c`? Given that its address is provided to `libdostuff` and it is "indirectly" called (though never directly)?**

Note: I happen to be writing both `foo` and `libdostuff`, and I'm wondering whether it makes more sense for the user-supplied functions to be `extern` and purely resolved at link-time, or passed into `libdostuff` via a user-supplied callback table supplied in an initialization function (e.g. `libdostuff_init(CallbackTable *user_callbacks)` where `CallbackTable` has a function pointer that would be initialized to point to `my_driver_fn`)

Comment: @M.M From an encapsulation perspective I agree. I just want to be sure I'm not handicapping the compiler at all, or invoking undefined behavior (compiler assumes it can't be called outside the module so does some shennanigans)

Comment: @M.M please submit an answer and I can give you my upvotes

Comment: Why have you tagged this C++ btw? It's another story there - you could use private member functions instead, and static members are perhaps not the best idea. C++ is not suitable for embedded systems overall - way too many mines that blow your whole leg off.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion this is good practice.  The `static` refers to the visibility of the name, and nothing else.

If the name is not needed to be used by other translation units, then marking it `static` reduces the risk of a clash in the "namespace" of externally visible functions .

Comment: Got it. I was just worried if labeling it static could affect link time optimization or introduce a side-effect. Sounds like not

Comment: @Brett The compiler should notice if you take the function's address anywhere . It's possible that a compiler might require some other indication if it doesn't realize the function is called. , I have heard of that, but I guess you can cross that bridge when you come to it.

Comment: To elaborate on that "should notice", if the compiler can't **prove** that the static function is not reachable from code it can't see, if can't make any transformations that would be invalid if it were reached from code it can't see.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE If it's conforming, of course :)  Although maybe that is grey when it comes to building static libraries  and deciding what to include.

Comment: @M.M: I don't follow. There's no problem here with static libraries.

Answer (score 8):

It is good practice and there are no negative side-effects like poorly-defined behavior.

There are many reasons for using `static`, like reducing namespace pollution and avoiding accidental/intentional calls. But the main reason is actually private encapsulation design and self-documenting code - to keep functions in the module they belong, so that the outside world need not worry about how and when to call them. They should only care about the external linkage functions you have declared in the public header file.

This is for example exactly how you design ISRs in embedded systems. They should always be declared `static` and be placed inside the driver controlling the hardware that the ISR relates to. All communication with the ISR, including race condition protection, should be placed encapsulated in that driver. The calling application never speaks directly with the ISR and should not need to worry about re-entrancy etc. Same thing with DMA buffers.

As an example of this, I always design a cyclic timer driver for all my MCU projects, where the API to the caller lets them register simple callback functions. The timer driver then calls the callback when the timer elapses, from inside the ISR. This can then be used as a general-purpose timer for all low priority tasks that need a timer: delays, de-bouncing etc. The caller then only needs to responsibly keep the callback function minimal and specify a time in ms, but the caller doesn't know or care about the timer hardware, and the timer hardware knows nothing of the callback it executes. Loose coupling in both directions. This timer API also serves as a HAL, so you can port the code to another MCU without changing the caller code - only change the underlying driver.

Comment: Though I suppose, one slight disadvantage is that you block inlining from the caller side unless you expose an `inline` function definition through a header file. (You can still always have it inlined inside the module where it belongs, of course.) But that's a very rare scenario - I rarely ever have a case where I actually need to do that for the sake of performance, and then I almost exclusively work with hard real-time systems.

Answer (score 3):

It is *good* practice.  It ensures the function can only be called by the code you have explicitly provided the callback to.  If it had external linkage, anything could call it, whether it makes sense or not.  It is clearly not impossible to abuse, but does make it more difficult to do accidentally.